# Save Jquery-generated html with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to save the Jquery-generated html on a page using PHP. Right now, the PHP function I have only saves code that was originally there.

My idea is for a user to generate a div with an image upon clicking a button (which works fine with jQuery), then for the PHP function to save that div on the page to a file called page-saved-with-divs.html.

I'm a beginner and open to suggestions.

Live page: http://colejohnsontrialsite.com/admin.php

Code:

```
 <?php
// Start the buffering //
ob_start();
?>
<!-- Content to save -->
<div id="images" style="border:2px solid gray">
    <!-- individual image Div's generated by jQuery go here -->
</div>

<?php
// echo '1'; 

// Get the content that is in the buffer and put it in your file //
file_put_contents('page-saved-with-divs.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

`

Comment: you would have to send the live html to the server. Source file won't help you

Comment: Thanks charliefl. Any suggestions on how to do this or more information?

Comment: bad approach, just save the necessary data, such as image source etc into db, either via a standard form or ajax and regenerate the html in php when the page is next loaded

Comment: This is what I ultimately ended up doing. Was a little hesitant to touch a database for this even though it seems ideal, and it was! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JQuery .html() Method and then Send it via Ajax.

JS code:

```
var html = $('#images').html();
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { code : html },
  dataType: "html"
});
```

PHP code:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
file_put_contents('page-saved-with-divs.html', $code);
```